# Timing of NotifyDataSetChanged() and calls to getView()

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm debugging an Android app with ListView and 2 threads -  a worker thread that updates the datastore and the main UI thread that does all the usual View stuff including displaying the listview.  (this is supposed to be a quick debug so I'm not mandated to change this that architecture).   I found that there was a thread collision because the worker thread was sometimes running when *getView()* was trying to consume stuff in the datastore.

So to prevent these collisions I create a semaphore with a count of 1 and the worker thread has to acquire it before touching the datastore arrays.   I also overrode *notifyDataSetChanged()* and put an aquire and release in it as well as some logging to instrument it.

```
@Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged()  {

    try {
        MyActivity.datastoreSemaphore.acquire();
        Log.d ("notifyDataSetChanged()...",   " acquired semaphore " );  
        try {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d ("notifyDataSetChanged()...",   "listItems.size()=" + String.valueOf(listItems.size()) + "  lv.getCount()=" + String.valueOf(lv.getCount()) );   //!! debugging
    } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e ("notifyDataSetChanged() inner catch ",   "Exception = " + e );   debugging   
        } finally {
            MyActivity.datastoreSemaphore.release();
            Log.d ("notifyDataSetChanged()...",   " released semaphore " );  
        }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         Log.e ("notifyDataSetChanged() outer catch ",   "Exception = " + e ); 
     }                                  
 }
```

I also instrumented *getView()* and **here's what I don't get:**  The trace shows *getView()* being called  OUTSIDE of when *notifyDataSetChanged()* is called.. . .

> 05-25 13:36:37.865: D/notifyDataSetChanged()...(21863):  acquired
>   semaphore   05-25 13:36:37.865: D/notifyDataSetChanged()...(21863):
>   listItems.size()=14  lv.getCount()=14
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.865: D/notifyDataSetChanged()...(21863):  released
>   semaphore
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.869: D/Entering getView() ...(21863): position=0
>   Adapter's getCount()=14
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.873: D/in getView() ...(21863): listItems size =14
>   position = 0
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.873: D/Exiting getView() ...(21863): position=0
>   Adapter's getCount()=14
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.873: D/Entering getView() ...(21863): position=1
>   Adapter's getCount()=14
>
> 05-25 13:36:37.873: D/in getView() ...(21863): listItems size =14
>   position = 1

In other words, according to LogCat, we call *notifyDataSetChanged()*; we aquire the semaphore, call the base method, return from the base method, release the semaphore, and **THEN** the *getView()* loop starts . . .

I was under the impression that *notifyDataSetChanged()* doesn't return until the whole *getView()* loop thing is done, but this seems to say otherwise.  What's happening here?  (**N.B.**, this question isn't really about the semaphore or thread collsions - I mentioned those to provide context -  the question is about the timing of the *getView()* loop WRT *notifyDataSetChanged()*  .)

**EDIT:**  the calls to *notifyDataSetChanged()* are run on the main UI thread via a runnable in runOnUIThread().   In the trace on the screen the TID for all the adapter stuff is shown to be the main UI thread.   I'll update the Question to reflect this.

Comment: In my opinion you're better off avoiding this problem entirely, by making sure `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called on the Main Thread. You can use a `Handler` on the `MainLooper` ([info](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/02/24/android-looper-anatomy/)) to jump from the worker thread to the Main Thread.

Comment: It is called on the main thread -  when I call it I do it with a runnable in runOnUIThread().   In the trace on the screen the TID for all the adapter stuff is shown to be the main UI thread.   I'll update the Question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` only fires the `onChanged()` method on its associated observers.

For `AdapterView` subclasses (such as `ListView`), this ends up calling `requestLayout()`, which [**schedules** a layout pass of the view tree](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29).

So, in short, it's not immediate. Eventually, `getView()` will be called for each item, but not before `notifyDataSetChanged()` has finished.

Anyway, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a worker thread is not a good idea. In fact, modifying an Adapter's contents from a background thread is likely to produce an exception. The message usually is:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of our adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your
>   adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.

Comment: I'm calling notifyDataSetChanged from a runnable in runOnUIThread().   In the trace on the screen the TID for all the adapter stuff is shown to be the main UI thread.   I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @user316117. Ok, I hadn't gotten that. Anyway, the answer is the same: notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't call getView() immediately.

Comment: OK, I'll count this particular question as answered and I'm starting a new question about its implications [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892736/timing-of-listview-layout-pass-how-to-keep-a-layout-pass-from-running-while-cha)