# Timing of ListView Layout Pass (how to keep a layout pass from running while changing the dataset?)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

An answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875855/timing-of-notifydatasetchanged-and-calls-to-getview) raised a different question for me.

When displaying a ListView you update the Data Set then call the adapter's *notifyDataSetChanged()*.   This calls *requestLayout()* and the Google documentation says "*This will **schedule** a layout pass of the view tree*"

So apparently we don't really know when that will take place.   But during the layout pass many of the custom overrides in the adapter such as *getView()* and *getCount()* will be accessing the data set.   So if the layout pass is run at an unknown time how do you know when it's safe to alter the data set?

I have a complex data set with multiple arrays that I need to keep synchronized with each other so I make my changes and call *notifyDataSetChanged()*.  After that I may need to make more changes (say, because new data has come in over the network) so how do I make sure a layout pass from the previous *notifyDataSetChanged()* isn't going to run in the middle of making the new changes?

Also, what does Google mean by "schedule" a layout pass?  When I log stuff in *getView()* the TID shown in the Logcat screen is the same as the main UI thread.  so after calling *notifyDataSetChanged()* if I check for new data and start updating my arrays how does Android manage to run the layout pass in that same thread?

Answer (score 3):

> So if the layout pass is run at an unknown time how do you know when
>   it's safe to alter the data set?

It's very simple: by only updating the data set in the UI thread, you're guaranteed to avoid any problems. Since the layout also occurs in the UI thread, both operations will, by necessity, execute serially. This can be achieved via `AsyncTask`, `Handler`, or any other method of thread communication.

> Also, what does Google mean by "schedule" a layout pass?

A message is posted for the UI thread's [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). It will be processed whenever said thread is idle.

Comment: Under what exact conditions does a thread go idle?  Even if everything is running in the same thread I'd have to make sure that I'm not in the middle of altering a dataset across idle states, or that I don't alter the dataset BEFORE the next idle state.  Or at least that altering the dataset and calling _notifyDataSetChanged()_ is atomic WRT idle states.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It's idle whenever no code is executing. If, in the UI thread, you do `a(); b(); c();` then you're sure that nothing will happen between `a()` and `b()`. No messages (not even drawing) can be processed until you relinquish control. That's why some actions (e.g. networking, file i/o) are prohibited or discouraged in the UI thread: the UI would be _completely_ frozen until they finish.

Comment: So the operating system's scheduler cannot make the thread go idle?  What about calling system routines, e.g., what if "b();" in your example is a system routine?    The arrays I'm updating and the code that updates them are complex and I want to be sure that they will remain atomic WRT to Idle states if an Idle state could cause a layout loop to happen.

Comment: Short of killing the process, you cannot interrupt the UI thread. To sum up: (1) do complex calculations in background, and produce a result, and (2) notify the UI thread to update the adapter with this result (this shouldn't be complex) and call notifyDataSetChanged().